# How to write the search result in to text file or load it to the table on SUD or GUI?

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to display the result on to table in GUI or SUD, which I got on querying the database. I am storing the result on the an object. When tried to show in on to table using existing code, for some reason it does not work, so I am thinking to write it to text file and read it from there as the existing code does it.

```
GlobalDim("NEWT,CheckCalLimits,CalFileName,DefFileNm")
NEWT = CLng(NEWT)

Dim myConn
Dim myCommand
Dim RS

Const DB_CONNECT_STRING = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=FWATRGSQLVCL2;Initial Catalog=calsample;user id ='sampleUser';password='sample@1'"

Set myConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set myCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command" )

myConn.Open DB_CONNECT_STRING
Set myCommand.ActiveConnection = myConn

myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT [heid],[zvalue],[limit],[type],[xchannel],[xvalue],[ychannel],[yvalue],[class],[descrip] FROM [calsimple].[dbo].[Req_Simpledata] where hwid= "&NEWT&""
```

Comment: It's comletely unclear to me what problem you're facing. What do you expect the code to do? What does it actually do? Please elaborate. [Edit] your question to do so, do not bury that information in comments.

Comment: Hello Ansgar,

As i stated above, the above code establishes the connection with SQL, the problem is next step, where i would like it either to show it on Table which is available on SUD or at least write it to text file, as some of the existing code supports reading from the file.